# Sending array of strings from JS to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any way to send array of strings from JavaScript to PHP?
I have a game that runs on localhost and I want to track it events using Google Analytics.
Google Analytics only track events that rise from multiple domain and subdomain.  Because my app runs on localhost I should send my data to an intermediate site and then send it to my google analytics account.
I need an intermediate site that gives these strings from an application that runs on localhost and send it to another site using JavaScript again?

I just don't know which languages I should used to do this intermediate task for me? 
Can php do this for me?

Comment: AJAX? http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Comment: You have to rephrase your question or it will be closed. Describe the practical case, not some vague thoughts. What intermediate site? what data you want to send back and forth? what application it as, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is always the most helpful:

```
// javascript part - use jQuery for example

$.ajax({
    url: "your-php-file.php",
    data: ['abc','def'] // your array
});

// PHP part your-php-file.php
die($_POST); // you will see the $_POST[data] = array('abc', 'def');
```

if you want to send the data the other way around, from PHP to javascript, add to your php file something like.

```
 echo json_encode (array('data_from_php'));

 // and in JS you have a callback on success for querying a php file
 $.ajax({
    url: "your-php-file.php",
    //data: [], // we dont send nothing this time
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // data will be a js array containing a string 'data_from_php'
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `data: {data: [...]}`, otherwise `$_POST` won't have a `data` entry.

Comment: we dont even need the line as we are not sending anything, but I'll modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to send data from a client to a server. I would recommend using a library like jQuery for these tasks as they make it much easier then writing them yourself. AJAX will be able to send data to a PHP script which can handle the data for you.

Here is an AJAX tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

And here is a link to jQuery AJAX tutorial:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd use php on your localhost, if this is for a once off or running as a service. If you need this to work on client machines you will run in to many security things to worry about.

In php use file() or file_get_contence()

Otherwise have a look at json_encode and decode in php to transfer objects