# create a javascript array with php in server

Tags: php, javascript

I know how to create Js array in php and send it to client. but How should I create a Js array with php and store them in server?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide some more information about your actual problem. For example which technology you want to use to store data. Why does it have to be a JavaScript array? What is it that you are trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: Maybe... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8397383/995958

Comment: $Felix, sorry for not being clear, so I guess I can generate the Js array in json and store them into a file. and later read it from that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send it as string - ["1","2","3"] and eval it on client side

```
var arrayFromServer = eval(the string from server);
```